# How to count number of bytes in a file using C?

Tags: c, algorithm, wc

How to count the number of bytes for a file using C?

Suppose the file below contains some code (data) in it. How does the word count (wc) program count the exact number of bytes for the specified file?

So for example if we have the following file:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("helloworld!");
}
```

I would like to know how to create a program that can count the number of bytes in that file.

The number of bytes for this file is 64 using Linux word count (wc)

```
cat helloworld.cpp | wc -c
64
```

Comment: Have a look at stat() and family.

Comment: The `getchar()` function (macro) reads a byte from standard input.  Count how many times you can call it before you get EOF and that tells you how many bytes are in the standard input stream.  A more general version of the code would have a function `int byte_count(FILE *fp)` that does the job.  Beware of very large files (2 GiB or more); you might need a different type than `int` as the return value for the count.  If you know the file name, you can consider using [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an excerpt from the [`stat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) sample

```
char filename[] = "helloworld.cpp";
struct stat sb;

if (stat(filename, &sb) == -1) {
    perror("stat");
}
else {
    printf("File size:                %lld bytes\n",
           (long long) sb.st_size);
}
```

Alternatively you can use the [getc()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) function

```
int bytes;
for(bytes = 0; getc(stdin) != EOF; ++bytes);
printf("File size:                %d bytes\n",bytes);
```